# How to match HTML layout units to A4 page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that I use to convert to PDF with headless chrome.

I set the style to

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And it's perfect for placing the HTML in the page's borders. However elements/text don't exactly match between the preview to the PDF itself, so it's not exactly "WYSIWYG".

What CSS styling do I need in order to make the HTML match the sizes of an A4, so that what I see on the page matches the A4 dimensions?

Sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @page {
      size: A4 portrait;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <div>
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <span>Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long </span>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

But because I didn't match the units to the actual A4 dimensions it's not what you get in the PDF:

[image]

Comment: "*However the CSS for the code itself doesn't match exactly*" - Please share a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thank you, added. It's very simple HTML page with a table. I am just not sure how to make the units fit an A4 dimensions. I mean that the text for example is not exactly what you see because it's all relative